# AEM 6.4 asset renditions, is it safe to remove 140x100 rendition?

Tags: aem, aem-6, dam, aem-touch-ui

By default DAM Update Asset  generate the following structure of renditions:
[image: Renditions structure]

I have verified our request log, where I could see all renditions except 140x100 are used on authoring instance.

Is it safe to remove 140x100 rendition? Is it used by default AEM components? Is it safe to remove that rendition if we use only Touch UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say if it is "safe" to delete the rendition. In theory, no component should "rely" on it being there. Well written asset code is always going to use some kind of fallback or look for the "nearest" rendition for a given size.

But there is no guarantee for that.

The better question is why you want to remove the rendition? Usually, it should be tiny so it should not waste a lot of space.

Nevertheless, if you intend to remove it, you should also update related workflows like the "DAM Update Asset" workflow that creates this rendition in the first place.

Comment: Potentially we will have a lot of images on our instance, so we want some optimization of Dam Update Asset workflow processing and make storage more lightweight

Comment: We have more than 10TB of assets in the DAM in some projects, so AEM can handle large amounts of assets. If you are really that concerned about this you should think about removing web renditions and have them created externally using tools like imgproxy or AWS Thumbor and stored/delivered outside of the DAM.

Comment: Yes, take a look at the workflow, you can edit it to generate only certain renditions and this way you can reduce the DAM size. Also, you can exclude the renditions from a package, and have them generated again when installing in another author instance, reducing the size of the package that you have to download and install.